# Visual studio nao reconhece html do .aspx

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Ao abrir qualquer arquivo .aspx, o visual studio não reconhece o código, fica tudo preto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também percebi que ao tentar criar um novo projeto, não aparece a opção web, sendo que instalei o Web Development.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Esse é o visual Studio 2015?

Comment: É sim amigo ...

Comment: Acho que deve ter algo errado com sua instalação, mas sobre a página, clique sobre ela com o direito e escolha abrir com.. escolha (Editor de Formulários da Web)

Comment: Open With => Web Forms Editor. e defina como padrão.

Comment: Já tentei isso, mas não vai, aparece o seguinte erro

Comment: The file cannot be opened with the selected editor. Please choose another editor

Comment: Não tem uma versão web nesse visual studio, você vai ter que corrigir isso.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Você pode fazer muito além dessa versão do Visual Studio, que além de ser antiga, não foi feita pra atender bem o desenvolvimento web.

Caso também tenha problemas das cores com o VSCode, recomendo dar uma olhada nos artigos adiante:

- https://www.itnota.com/making-visual-studio-code-colorize-classic-asp-code/
- https://github.com/ilich/vscode-classic-asp
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ilich8086.classic-asp

Tente isto como alternativa.